# is transform a class or a property in Unity?

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, properties

I am new to programming, could someone help me to understand it better.
when I check the Unity Manual it shows that transform is a class in Unity Engine, but when I hold my mouse over a transform in c# code, it shows transform is a property of the component class, I mean the icon for the property is shown(small French). why it does not show class when the mouse is over it? any help or link to study is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: `transform` is a property and its type is `Transform`.

Comment: then why when I check the Unity Manual it shows that transform is a class in Unity Engine?

Comment: Well as your image shows you: `Component.transform` is the name of the **property** that has as **type** `Transform` which is a **class** ...

Comment: thanks for your answer. when we make a new class, do we create a new dataType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform is a class in UnityEngine, each GameObject has one.
.transform is a property of a MonoBehaviour, that returns a Transform instance associated with GameObject that current (this) MonoBehaviour has.

You can assume it is defined as (although in reality it is optimized and faster than that)

```
Transform transform {get { return GetComponent<Transform>(); }}
```

Comment: Thanks, I almost get it, I did not notice that Transform as a class is written with capital T and transform as the property of MonoBehavior is written with small t. I checked the inherited property of MonoBehavior in the Unity manual and I found it, thanks again.

Comment: how? should I press the Blue button?